# Does Server.ClearError() prevent IIS Rapid Fail Protection

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, error-handling

In our ASP.Net application we usually try to handle all our exceptions by catching them in relevant places to give the end user useful error messages, but some exceptions are impossible for us to catch due the place they are thrown.

This is an issue to our server setup since we want to keep the IIS Rapid Fail Protection working as intended, and all errors to be written to our custom error log. So to avoid unexpected resets of the server and flooding our error log, I have added some code in Global.asax.cs to suppress certain kinds of errors. At the moment we are looking at two kinds of HttpExceptions thrown by the IIS itself, to prevent too long URLs (based on the maxUrlLength setting), and to prevent faulty WebResource or ScriptResource requests. These are impossible for us to prevent due to some webcrawlers generating them.

What I'm interested in knowing, that is difficult for me to find info on anywhere is:

1. Can the referenced HttpExceptions even potentially cause the Rapid
   Fail Protection to restart the server? I'm told that any uncaught
   exception can cause it, but it seems illogical to me that this kind
   of exception should be able to cause it.
2. If I call Server.ClearError() in the Application_Error() event, is that enough to suppress errors that could cause a rapid fail protection restart?
   Or is it already too late at this point? Since we're already in the
   process of responding to an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rapid-Fail Protection (here, RFP) feature is meant to protect the system from application pools and worker processes that are not starting properly or are failing often. These issues could be caused by your application(s) or an IIS worker process. The official (albeit old) list of causes can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787273(WS.10).aspx).

1. Not directly. If the logic that is attempting to handle the error fails, the worker process could crash. This would trigger RFP. Usually, this will not happen because IIS will try to handle an exception in `Application_Error`.
2. If your application has gracefully handled the exception in `Application_Error`, then it stops there. Your exception was "unhandled" at the application level, but IIS was able to handle it (usually serving the "yellow screen of death"). Therefore, the worker process is still healthy and RFP will not be triggered.

---

I have seen an IIS worker process crash under the following conditions:

- Recursive call results in an infinite loop.
- Insufficient system resources to process a request (out of memory or memory limit reached).